How to bypass token interceptor for specific API call in angular-auth-oidc-client?
I'm using the angular-auth-oidc-client library for handling authentication in my Angular application. The library automatically attaches a token to the headers of all outgoing HTTP requests using an interceptor.
However, I have a specific API call where I don't want to pass the token in the header. I need to bypass the interceptor for this particular request, but it seems that the interceptor is always adding the token.
I looked into the library documentation but didn't find a clear solution for excluding specific requests from token attachment.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-auth-oidc-client

You can use HttpBackend to make API calls, these API calls are not intercepted maybe that is what you are looking for.
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpRequest, HttpBackend } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
        <div><h3>Response</h3>{{response | async | json}}</div>
        <div><h3>Response2</h3>{{response2 | async | json}}</div>
        <button (click)="request()">Make request with http backend</button>
        <button (click)="request2()">Make request with normal httpClient</button>`,
})
export class AppComponent {
  response: Observable<any>;
  response2: Observable<any>;
  constructor(private backend: HttpBackend, private http: HttpClient) {}

  request() {
    const req = new HttpRequest(
      'GET',
      'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1'
    );
    this.response = this.backend.handle(req);
  }

  request2() {
    this.response2 = this.http.get(
      'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1'
    );
  }
}

Stackblitz Demo

You can change secureRoutes config to achieve that. AuthModule in angular-auth-oidc-client package will only add the token to the requests that their URLs exist in that config.

I've looked into this option, but it doesn't solve the issue because my endpoint is the same; however, that particular API doesn't require any token to be passed.

Can you divide them into multiple endpoints? for example https://endpoint/api1, https://endpoint/api2 and so on.

The objective here is the opposite; I want to exclude a specific API with a particular route.

keycloak-angular has a config property called 'excludeBearerUrls' - to emulate this using angular-auth-oidc-client you can use an interceptor:
// app.config.ts

        {
            provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
            useClass: AuthInterceptor,
            multi: true,
        },

// auth-interceptor.ts

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
import { OidcSecurityService } from 'angular-auth-oidc-client';

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor {
  constructor(private oidcSecurityService: OidcSecurityService) {}

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const excludedUrls = ['/api/public', '/api/open']; // Your excluded URLs
    
    if (excludedUrls.some(url => req.url.includes(url))) {
      return next.handle(req);
    }
    
    return this.oidcSecurityService.interceptor(req, next);
  }
}


